# Succinct way of updating a single field of a django model object

Tags: django, django-models

To update (and save) the field on an object you do:

```
>>> product = Product.objects.get(name='Venezuelan Beaver Cheese')
>>> product.number_sold = 4
>>> product.save()
```

Is there a way to compress the last two lines into a single line, like:

```
product.update(number_sold=4)
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yup.

```
Product.objects.filter(name='Venezuelan Beaver Cheese').update(number_sold=4)
```

If you have a model instance you changed and want to save only specific fields to the database, do that:

```
product.name = "New name of the product"
product.save(update_fields=['name'])
```

Comment: Link to the documentation: [Updating multiple objects at once](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) (do not be fooled by the title, you can select one row and this way update only one).

Comment: Django 1.5 now allows you to update only one field on save() with the update_fields parameter  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save

Comment: @rschwieb Updated my answer instead.

Answer (score 7):

@Lovelive's answer is the best way to go. The only downside is that you don't get the instance with that. So you still need the `product = Product.objects.get(...)` line if you need `product` for anything else. However, it does cover the use-case scenario of "compress the last two lines into a single line" perfectly.

Just to play devil's advocate, you could also add a method to your model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, k, v)
        self.save()
```

Comment: I have `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'` on this method

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation this is also an alternative:

```
product.save(update_fields=["number_sold"])
```

Comment: This saves the number_sold field. But it requires you to have modified the object's number_sold value already before hand. The question is about whether you can do both of those things in a single line